# can you change this code JavaScript without button

Tags: javascript

I have some code to detect what browser a visitor is using.
The code runs when a button is clicked. I want to change it so it displays this in middle of the web page: `"Your browser is Chrome"` (or whatever browser they're using).

```
<p>What is the name(s) of your browser?</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() { 
    if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
        alert('Opera');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {
        alert('Chrome');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        alert('Safari');
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {
        alert('Firefox');
    } else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) { //IF IE > 10
        alert('IE'); 
    } else {
        alert('unknown');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the name to a variable and then set the text of an element.
here is an example:

```
<p id="demo">Your browser is <span></span>.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() { 
    var browserName;

    if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
        browserName = 'Opera';
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {
        browserName = 'Chrome';
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
        browserName = 'Safari';
    } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {
        browserName = 'Firefox';
    } else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) { //IF IE > 10
        browserName = 'IE'; 
    } else {
        browserName = 'unknown';
    }

    document.querySelector('#demo > span').innerText = browserName;
}

window.onload = function() {
    myFunction();
}
</script>
```

Comment: do not work .. just see " Your browser is ."

Comment: Because you need to call myFunction, the code is now updated

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQueryUi` you can use dialogs and display them in the center of the viewport.

```js
(function myFunction() {
        var browserName;

        if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1 ) {
            browserName = 'Opera';
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 ) {
            browserName = 'Chrome';
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
            browserName = 'Safari';
        } else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) {
            browserName = 'Firefox';
        } else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) { //IF IE > 10
            browserName = 'IE';
        } else {
            browserName = 'unknown';
        }

        document.querySelector('#demo > span').innerText = browserName;
        $('#dialog').dialog();
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p id="demo">Your browser is <span></span>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not need button , I want automatically view "your browser is chrome " when open the page without button only text

Comment: @maahdisaad yes, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

About your question:

> «The code runs when a button is clicked. I want to change it so it
>   displays this in middle of the web page: "Your browser is Chrome"».

You need to display this message when the page is loaded.

You can do something like this with pure **JavaScript** and **CSS3**.

```js
(function() {
  function myFunction() {
    var browser = "";
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
      browser = 'Opera';
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
      browser = 'Chrome';
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
      browser = 'Safari';
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
      browser = 'Firefox';
    } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
      browser = 'IE';
    } else {
      browser = 'unknow';
    }
    return browser;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").children[0].innerHTML = myFunction();
})();
```

```css
#window {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #b8d1ea);
  border: solid 1px #b8d1ea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: #2a3848 10px 10px 10px 1px;
  margin: 10px auto; /* Center the div in the middle of the page. */
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="window">
  <p id="demo">Your browser is <span></span>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you  that I wanted

Comment: Oh, I'm glad about that. Don't forget to accept this answer to help to other users to find this solution as proper.